# Create a Regex to to check for two Alpha and 4 Numeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi I am trying to create a regex so it validate the following
Should be 6 character long, should start with AT or UN + 4 digits from 0 to 9. No restriction on digits.

So it should be AT1234 or UN1234. (Un or AT can be upper or lower)

I tried below but I am always getting false in jQuery

```
 /^[ATUN]\d{ 4 }$/
```

**Update**

It is working. I found first that the code was not working later I noticed that there is a space { 4 }.  After I removed the spaces the code worked as expected.

```
if (dangerous == "Yes" && ($("#dangerousUS1").val() != ''))
        {
        /*var dangUS1 = $("#dangerousUS1").val().toUpperCase();*/
        var regxUITest = /^(?:ID|UN)\d{ 4 }$/i;
        instead
        var regxUITest = /^(?:ID|UN)\d{4}$/i;
```

These are working as well

```
/^(ID|UN)\d{4}$/
/^(ID|UN)\d{4}$/i
```

Comment: `[ATUN]` should be `(AT|UN)` Parentheses are for grouping, square brackets are for character sets.

Comment: you're close, try `/^(AT|UN)\d{ 4 }$/i`. the `(AT|UN)` says match either of these values and the `/i` bit tells it to be case insensitive. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more details on the switches.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the anchor on the link for RegEx switches, here's the link with the anchor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ATUN]` matches a single character from the character class, i.e. `A`, `T`, `U`, or `N`.

You can use the non-capturing group `(?:AT|UN)` to match exactly `AT` or `UN`.